# Extracting font from HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is it possible to extract the font from an html5 canvas?

Today's Google doodle has a crossword which is a canvas.

For example, is it possible to find out the font of DNA in the crossword?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you the technical howto (I spent ages poking around Opera Dragonfly, until I finally stumbled upon it), but I finally worked out that the Crossword Grid font is [Coming Soon](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Coming+Soon) by Open Window.